# Kotlin: retain coroutine context in scenario with nested runBlocking

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm fairly new to kotlin coroutines, and I have what I think is a somewhat esoteric use case related to how `runBlocking` and coroutine contexts interact.

To start with, a simple example. Let's say I've got a dead simple context element. Nothing fancy.

```
class ExampleContext(val s: String) : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(Key) {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<ExampleContext>
}
```

When I run these examples, they behave exactly the way I'd expect them to:

```
runBlocking(ExampleContext("foo")) {
    println(coroutineContext[ExampleContext.Key]?.s) // prints "foo
}

runBlocking(ExampleContext("foo")) {
    launch {
        println(coroutineContext[ExampleContext.Key]?.s) // prints "foo"
    }
}

runBlocking(ExampleContext("foo")) {
    launch(ExampleContext("bar")) {
        println(coroutineContext[ExampleContext.Key]?.s) // prints "bar"
    }
}
```

When I do **this** it prints null (as I would expect it to, because it runBlocking defaults to having `EmptyContext` in its constructor):

```
runBlocking(ExampleContext("foo")) {
    runBlocking {
        println(coroutineContext[ExampleContext.Key]?.s) // prints null
    }
}
```

So here's my conundrum. [The docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) (and all the guidance I've found on the web) basically say ***don't do this***: `runBlocking` is supposed to be run at the outermost layer of the coroutine logic and that's it. No nesting. What I'm working on is a library that needs to populate some context for access inside code *that I don't own* that gets called later (basically, you can think of it like an interceptor). The rough pseudocode looks a little like this:

```
class MyLibrary(otherPeoplesLogic: OtherPeoplesBusinessLogic) {

    fun <IN, OUT> execute(input: IN): OUT {
        ... do my library's thing, including adding in a custom context element ...
        try {
            return otherPeoplesLogic.execute(input)
        } finally {
            ... do my library's cleanup ...
        }
    }
}
```

To support coroutines in `OtherPeoplesBusinessLogic`, all I'd really have to do is add `runBlocking` like this:

```
class MyLibrary(otherPeoplesLogic: OtherPeoplesBusinessLogic) {

    fun <IN, OUT> execute(input: IN): OUT {
        ... do my library's thing ...
        runBlocking(myCustomContext) {
            try {
                return otherPeoplesLogic.execute(input)
            } finally {
                ... do my library's cleanup ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So long as all `OtherPeoplesBusinessLogic::execute` does is `launch`/`async`/etc, everything is fine: `myCustomContext` will be accessible. What I'm worried about is what happens if `OtherPeoplesBusinessLogic::execute` (which I'm not in control of) misbehaves and does its own `runBlocking` call with no context argument passed at all: what I think will happen is that `myCustomContext` will just silently get dropped like the example above. Not good, because it needs to be accessible.

Phew. A lot of explanation. Thanks for bearing with me. :)

So my ultimate question here is this: is there anything I can do (outside of scolding the users of my library to not call `runBlocking`) to prevent an accidental nested `runBlocking` call from dropping my context? Or am I just out of luck here and should scrap the whole idea?

Comment: Why do you care if `otherPeoplesLogic` sees your custom element if it doesn't know it and simply ignore it? I don't think your problem is related to nested `runBlocking()`. You simply can't force `otherPeoplesLogic` to use your context everywhere in their code. They can start entirely new coroutine, for example they could use their own `CoroutineScope` and then your context is not at all used. `runBlocking()` is yet another way to start a coroutine.

Comment: OK. I had a feeling that was going to be the case. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, in the documentation of your library you can specify the contract that some further functionality has to be executed from the same context you provided. This is similar to the requirement that we can't switch threads.